# Есть ли в mongodb возможность провести операцию "найти или создать" с массивом?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Я использую mongoose. У меня есть следующие 2 схемы:

1. Жанр книги (Genre)

   `{
     text:{type:String, unique: true}
   }`
2. Книга (Book)

   `{
     title: String,
     author: String,
     genres: [{genre:{type:Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'genre'}}]
   }`

Когда пользователь добавляет книгу, мне нужно проверить, есть ли жанры, и если нету, то вставить новые. Так вот, я не пойму как мне это сделать. Конечно, можно по 1 это делать, но мне кажется это не очень хорошей идеей. Вот и появилась мысль, есть ли какие инструменты или чтото похожее чтобы можно было решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте `$addToSet`

```
Book.findOne({author: customAuthor}, {$addToSet: {$all: customGenreIdsArray}})
```

Comment: вместо $all нужно использовать $each